# Select users that have more received photos than sent photos

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with this SQL query. Say I have these two tables

```
**USERS**
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | james |
|  2 | tom   |
|  3 | kate  |
+----+-------+

**PHOTOS**
+-----------+-----------+---------+
|   name    | sent_from | sent_to |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| beach.jpg |         1 |       2 |
| trees.jpg |         3 |       1 |
| earth.jpg |         2 |       1 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

How could I get, using one SQL query, all the users that have more sent_to associated with their id than sent_from ?

Comment: please show your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of this as aggregating the data twice and then doing the comparison:

```
select sf.sent_from
from (select sent_from, count(*) as numsent
      from photos
      group by sent_from
     ) sf left outer join
     (select sent_to, count(*) as numrecv
      from photos
      group by sent_to
     ) st
     on sf.sent_from, st.sent_to
where numsent > numrecv;
```

If you want user information, then join that in.

An alternative way restructures the data first and then does the aggregation:

```
select who
from (select sent_from as who, 1 as sent_from, 0 as sent_to
      from photos
      union all
      select sent_to as who, 0, 1
      from photos
     ) p
group by who
having sum(sent_from) > sum(sent_to);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here is something that might help you:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT `id`, `name`, 
       IFNULL((SELECT count(*) FROM `photos` WHERE `sent_from` = `users`.`id`),0) AS `sent_from_count`,
       IFNULL((SELECT count(*) FROM `photos` WHERE `sent_t`o = `users`.`id`),0) AS `sent_to_count`
       FROM `users`) AS `t1`
    WHERE `t1`.`sent_to_count` > `t1`.`sent_to_count`
```